# Mutt send-hook to sanitize "to" address?

Tags: mutt

Is there a hook available that allows to sanitize email recipients before sending the email?

Ideally, upon pressing "y", the name part is removed from all recipients and only the email address remains:

```
Mike Anderson <ma@example.com>, Andi Mikeson <am@example.com>
```

becomes:

```
ma@example.com, am@example.com
```

Comment: You could of course insert some filtering script *between Mutt and your SMTP client* (making Mutt pipe header+mail into the script, having the script call the SMTP client with the altered header+mail).  But Mutt can probably do this already...

Comment: Yeah, that would be an option too. My current workflow is: new mail -> enter recipients via goobook -> compose message in vim -> vim macro to sanitize the "TO:" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you already got a macro to sanitise the `To:` line in Vim, so an easy solution might be to

1. create a secondary `vimrc` with [an `autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-define) that triggers your macro on [`BufWrite`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWrite)
2. set Vim with this configuration as your editor in Mutt.